# Is the way I'm writing my Vue components correct?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Here's the way I am currently writing my Vue components. E.g.

```
    <template>
     <NavBar></NavBar>
     <div class="Footer">
      <div class="left">
       <p>I'm a cool footer on the Left!</p>
      </div>
      <div class="middle">
      </div>
      <div class="right">
       <p>I'm a cool footer on the Right!</p>
      </div>
     </div>
    </template>

   <script>
    import NavBar from './NavBar.vue';
    export default {
     name: 'Footer',
     components: {
       NavBar
     }
     data () {
      return {
      }
     },
     methods: {
     } 
    }
```

My question is should I be writing my components like this instead? And if so, what is the difference?

```
    Vue.component('my-component', {
     template: '<div>A custom component!</div>'
    })

    new Vue({
     el: '#example'
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official guide explains the difference here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html

The short explanation is that the `<template>...` syntax is used for single-file components (e.g. `my-component.vue`) whereas the `vue.component...` syntax is used alongside the `new Vue({...` declaration.

Full quote from the guide:

*In many Vue projects, global components will be defined using `Vue.component`, followed by `new Vue({ el: '#container' })` to target a container element in the body of every page.
This can work very well for small to medium-sized projects, where JavaScript is only used to enhance certain views. In more complex projects however, or when your frontend is entirely driven by JavaScript, these disadvantages become apparent:*

- *Global definitions force unique names for every component*
- *String templates lack syntax highlighting and require ugly slashes
  for multiline HTML*
- *No CSS support means that while HTML and JavaScript are modularized
  into components, CSS is conspicuously left out*
- *No build step restricts us to HTML and ES5 JavaScript, rather than
  preprocessors like Pug (formerly Jade) and Babel*

*All of these are solved by single-file components with a `.vue` extension, made possible with build tools such as Webpack or Browserify.*

Comment: I'd go with whatever makes your development easiest and keeps it easy to understand the application structure.